# Why the incorrect toggle action in Polymer core-list selection?

Tags: javascript, polymer

In the code below the Selected: {{selection.app_id}} is displayed correctly when I click on a selection.  However in the JS console, I get  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'app_id' of undefined the first time the item is clicked and then when I click again it outputs the correct app_id.  At the same time Selected: {{selection.app_id}} clears the app_id.

Eventually the function loadApp is going render another element within the core-list parent. But I need to fix this problem first.  Any ideas?

```
<polymer-element name="tdv-apps" attributes="username">
  <template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tdv-apps.css">
    <div>My Apps
    <core-list id="appsList" data="{{data}}" scrollTarget="{{$.contentPanel.scroller}}" height="100%" selectionEnabled="true" selection="{{selection}}">
       <br/>Selected: {{selection.app_id}}
      <template>
        <div id="current" class="row {{ {selected: selected} | tokenList }}" layout horizontal on-tap="{{loadApp}}">
        <p class="app">Name: {{model.name}} -- ID: {{model.app_id}} <br/> Description: {{model.description}}</p>
        </div>
      </template>
    </core-list>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    (function () {

      Polymer('tdv-apps', {
        ready: function() {
           //apps_list will be pulled from the server via JS or a core-ajax element 
          this.data = [
            {name: "App 1", app_id: 'tdvapp-001', description:" App number 1."},
            {name: "App 2", app_id: 'tdvapp-002', description:" App number 2."},
            {name: "App 3", app_id: 'tdvapp-003', description:" App number 3."},
            {name: "App 4", app_id: 'tdvapp-004', description:" App number 4."},
            {name: "App 5", app_id: 'tdvapp-005', description:" App number 5."},
            {name: "App 6", app_id: 'tdvapp-006', description:" App number 6."},
            {name: "App 7", app_id: 'tdvapp-007', description:" App number 7."},
            {name: "App 8", app_id: 'tdvapp-008', description:" App number 8."},
            {name: "App 9", app_id: 'tdvapp-009', description:" App number 9."},
            {name: "App 10", app_id: 'tdvapp-010', description:" App number 10."},
            {name: "App 11", app_id: 'tdvapp-011', description:" App number 11."},
            {name: "App 12", app_id: 'tdvapp-012', description:" App number 12."}
          ];        
        },

        loadApp: function(){
          console.log(this.$.appsList.selection.app_id)
        },

      }); // Polymer close

    })();
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `loadApp` function, called by your `on-tap`, is called before the component sets the `selection` attribute.

The first time it's called, nothing is selected at the moment of the call.

A way to do what you want if not using the `on-tap` but a listener to the change on `selection`:

```
<polymer-element name="tdv-apps" attributes="username">
  <template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tdv-apps.css">
    <div>My Apps
    <core-list id="appsList" data="{{data}}" scrollTarget="{{$.contentPanel.scroller}}" 
               height="100%" selectionEnabled="true" selection="{{selection}}">
      Selected: {{selection.app_id}}
      <template>
        <div id="current" class="row {{ {selected: selected} | tokenList }}" layout horizontal >
        <p class="app">Name: {{model.name}} -- ID: {{model.app_id}} <br/> Description: {{model.description}}</p>
        </div>
      </template>
    </core-list>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    (function () {

      Polymer('tdv-apps', {
        ready: function() {
           //apps_list will be pulled from the server via JS or a core-ajax element 
          this.data = [
            {name: "App 1", app_id: 'tdvapp-001', description:" App number 1."},
            {name: "App 2", app_id: 'tdvapp-002', description:" App number 2."},
            {name: "App 3", app_id: 'tdvapp-003', description:" App number 3."},
            {name: "App 4", app_id: 'tdvapp-004', description:" App number 4."},
            {name: "App 5", app_id: 'tdvapp-005', description:" App number 5."},
            {name: "App 6", app_id: 'tdvapp-006', description:" App number 6."},
            {name: "App 7", app_id: 'tdvapp-007', description:" App number 7."},
            {name: "App 8", app_id: 'tdvapp-008', description:" App number 8."},
            {name: "App 9", app_id: 'tdvapp-009', description:" App number 9."},
            {name: "App 10", app_id: 'tdvapp-010', description:" App number 10."},
            {name: "App 11", app_id: 'tdvapp-011', description:" App number 11."},
            {name: "App 12", app_id: 'tdvapp-012', description:" App number 12."}
          ];        
        },

        selectionChanged: function(){
          console.log(this.$.appsList.selection.app_id)
        },

      }); // Polymer close

    })();
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

A Plunker is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/rOuNPu99D7ROX4ewbLnK?p=preview

I hope it helps :)